# iPhone webview in uitableview

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

```
UIWebView *webview=[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 150, 120)];
NSString *media=@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kG2BYhjQIKQ";
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:youTubeVideoHTML,media, 150, 120];

[webview loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
[cell.contentView addSubview:webview];
```

It is not working , it displays only white view.

Comment: what does youTubeVideoHTML contain?

Comment: problem with NSString *html in your code

Comment: I want to display thumnail of video in cell

Comment: The NSString *html seems to be a bit strange. What does youTubeViewHTML contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To play youtube video on webView try the followings:

```
NSString *youTubeVideoHTML = @"<html><head>\
                          <body style=\"margin:0\">\
                          <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
                          width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
                          </body></html>";

    // Populate HTML with the URL and requested frame size
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:youTubeVideoHTML, urlString, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];

    // Load the html into the webview
    [self loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

[webview loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
 is use to load into the UITextview
if you want to use UIwebview means

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```